# How to Fill a path excluding certain areas(paths) C# Graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, dlib

Right now im developing a Windows forms C# App, it detects your face with dlib (https://github.com/takuya-takeuchi/DlibDotNet)
It gets the 68 face landmarks with Points

Face landmarks with its points: [image]

And so withthis i have made a Graphics Path for the lips, nose, eyes, and eyebrows and a path that goes around all the face, my question is, is it possible to substract the eyes, eyebrows, lips and nose paths from the one that covers all the face to paint all the face "excluding" those areas?

I found this to be possible in xaml:

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/draw-shapes-and-paths?view=vs-2017)
[image]

So is it possible to do the ExcludeOverlap or the Substract with Graphics paths and a bitmap in C#?
And if so how?

(I know it's almost an unspoken rule to post some code but what i just basically did is create a graphics path for each part of the face, and then paint them on a bitmap with Graphics.FillPath())

Comment: With a little luck and testing it will happen all by itself. You need to play with adding shapes to the path, clsoing figures and finding the right windingmode.

Comment: Since i dont know what windingmode is i'll asumme that, there may be the answer, ill check it out.

Comment: It is a GraphicsPath property that controls how overlapping areas are filled.

Comment: Ah that may be it, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Um, I always fail to remember the right name: It is [GraphicsPath.FillMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.fillmode?view=netframework-4.7.2) - Without overlapping you do not need to change anything, just create a number of paths and add them to the out one with `gp0.AddPath(gp1, false);` With overlapping you may want to change from default `Alternate` to `Winding`..

Comment: Note that this is not as powerful as the examples from xaml. For th full set of set operation you would need to use a region but would lose anti-aliasing..

Comment: Oh i was checking just this, it actually seems that does the trick, for the time being quality isnt a priority so this works out perfectly well for me.
If you want to post it as an answer i would gladly mark it as correct.

Comment: The question is too broad. Please break it to smaller specific questions, for example about creating the union of two circles or intersection or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*is it possible to substract the eyes, eyebrows, lips and nose paths from the one that covers all the face to paint all the face "excluding" those areas?*

This is not only possible; in fact this is the default for combining `GraphicsPaths`: You add smaller, inner paths to a larger outer path and when you fiil it they will be holes.

Not however that this will also happen when you overlay further paths over the 'holes' resulting in positve areas within the holes.

To makes all paths combine additively (*Or* -ing) you would change the `FillMode` property to `Winding`. The Default is `Alternative' which will create holes (*Xor* -ing the araes.)

To get full control you could use [`Regions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.region?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). They can be combined at will with the whole set of set operations. But they will not support antialiasing, so the curves and tilted lines will look rugged.

Example:

[image]

```
private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    GraphicsPath gp0 = new GraphicsPath();
    GraphicsPath gp1 = new GraphicsPath();
    GraphicsPath gp2 = new GraphicsPath();
    GraphicsPath gp3 = new GraphicsPath();
    GraphicsPath gp4 = new GraphicsPath();

    gp0.AddEllipse(11, 11, 333, 333);
    gp1.AddEllipse(55, 55, 55, 55);
    gp2.AddEllipse(222, 55, 66, 66);
    gp3.AddEllipse(55, 222, 99, 222);
    gp4.AddLine(66, 123, 234, 77);

    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Empty, 12f))
    gp4.Widen(pen);

    gp0.AddPath(gp1, true);
    gp0.AddPath(gp2, true);
    gp0.AddPath(gp3, true);
    gp0.AddPath(gp4, true);

    gp0.FillMode = FillMode.Alternate;
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Goldenrod, gp0);
}
```